# Eloquent relationship doesnt work on production

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

So I am writing a code where users can invite people to register using their referral code. a user should be able to determine the people he has invited using the relationship $user->invitees(). It works great locally. But on production, it doesn't.

```
public function invitees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referrer', 'referral_code');
}
```

I learnt it is because the relationship might return null in some cases:

the referrer and the referral_code field might be null(in some situation, like when a user registered directly without being invited by someone) thereby causing the `invitees()` relationship to return null

I read somewhere that this could be the reason.

is this true? and if yes, how can I tackle this?

Comment: Hi, What is your error? 
Did you try to check $invitees =  $user->invitees() ? $user->invitees() : 0;

Comment: The error is that it returns an empty collection when I know it shouldn't

Comment: Are you sure isn't something wrong with the data in the tables?
Did you checked with an sql query for that case? I ask you that because you sad that is OK on dev environment.

Comment: If you run the code  $invitees = $user->invitees(); if (!$invitees->isEmpty()) { "do what you have to do" }  does it work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case maybe you need to use $user->invitees - without ()- because the function it returning a relationship.

And maybe you will have some situation when the user will not have invitations so you will need to validate this with

```
if($user->invitees->count()) {}
```

if count is > 0 it will be true.

Please try and let me know... if you receive the error please paste here.